# php-fpm - How to log `NOTICE`s to stdout, everything else (`E_ALL`) to stderr?

Tags: php, logging, php-fpm, php.ini, php8.1

As far as I understood the configuration docs, it is only possible to enable/disable specific log levels:

```
# ini, E_NOTICE disabled entirely.
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors=stderr
```

To my understanding, in this case we would not get the `E_NOTICE`s anywhere, meaning we wouldn't know about them.

**Is there a native way to direct `E_NOTICE`s to stdout and anything else to stderr?**

**If not what is the easiest workaround?**

The given config (and question) is a simplification, as we would want to direct multiple error levels to stdout, others to stderr while some should still be disabled entirely.

Context: In our case php-fpm runs in a kubernetes container so logging should write to stdout or stderr.